# Where can I find out the documentation about status code of GNSearchResult?

Tags: android, gracenote

I'm using GNSDK API for recording the Song from microphone and then recognize it.

```
GNOperations.recognizeMIDStreamFromMic(this, config);
```

It was working fine with almost 90-95% accuracy, but since last 2-3 days it is returning Status Code: **9001** in almost all cases.
So where can I find out the status code related documentation.

Am I exceeding the limit of API calls in Community Free Plan? If yes, then how many API calls we can make for the above mentioned method.

PS: I'm not able to find in this [Gracenote Android Developers Guide](http://developer.gracenote.com/sites/default/files/mc_android/html/Content/PDFs/Mobile-Client-SDK-Android-Developers-Guide-o.pdf)

Comment: Regardless of the error, exactly which SDK are you using.? The Gracenote Android Developers Guide you shared refers to the Mobile Client SDK which is considered deprecated. You should be using GNSDK for Mobile SDK.

Comment: Yeah, I am using GN_Music_SDK.jar the deprecated one I guess. Thanks :)